# ASP.NET Core Hangfire Production deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am a bit confused

I read about this

https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

I have a recurring job like this

```
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TerminaTurnos>(t => t.TerminaAsync(), "58 6,14,22 * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

If I deploy to IIS, do i have do configure anything else on my application? 
Can I trust that the jobs will always run even if IIS restarts?

Comment: I've had similar concerns with HostedServices, which is an alterntive to hang fire, and it's built into .net core.  You may have to ping yourself with a keep alive,  Some shared hosts will Shut down your application until a request comes in.  However if its a RecurringJob it should automatically start when your application is alive

Comment: I see thanks for the info, I guess i'll keep checking it when i deploy it to production on the first weeks

Comment: I've posted a few questions on it but I haven't gotten any definitive answers.  When I was checking with Hosted services they were running fine, but the issue is when you test in staging you're mostly using IIS Express, If anything run a manually test using IIS, and restart the service etc..